# How to insert datetime into a SQL Server database table with a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've created the following stored procedure:

```
create proc sp
    @Tablename nvarchar(max), @Dt datetime
as
begin
    exec('insert '+@Tablename+' values('+@Dt+')')
end
```

When I execute that stored procedure

```
exec sp 'TbName','2012-12-10 13:38:00.000'
```

I got this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '10'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which "SQL Database"?

Comment: when creating the sql string to exec convert `@Dt` to `varchar` and put it in between `''` so the string should then be `insert into tbl values ('yyyymmdd')`

Comment: I should also say that this can be considered to be a code smell, it is vulnerable to sql injection, you should read up on the pros and cons of dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the date value.  Otherwise it is interpreted as numbers and other things:

```
create proc sp
    @Tablename nvarchar(max), @Dt datetime
as
begin
    exec('insert '+@Tablename+' values(''+@Dt+'')')
end;
```

When writing such code, it is good practice to put separate the variable substitution from the `exec()`.  That way you can easily print out the string:

```
create proc sp
    @Tablename nvarchar(max), @Dt datetime
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @sql = 'insert '+@Tablename+' values(''+@Dt+'')';
    exec(@sql);
end;
```

If you had printed out what you were executing, you might have spotted the problem right away.